# Is "hanging bats" a participial phrase, gerund phrase, or simple noun phrase?

Tags: gerunds, present-participles, noun-phrases, ing

In the sentence "Hanging bats populate most of the caves in North America," what is the role of "hanging bats"?  I believe it is a simple noun phrase containing the participle "hanging" (which modifies "bats"), while another individual referred to it as a gerund phrase.

I should mention that the quiz question is "What kind of phrase is underlined?"

Answer (score 2):

*Hanging bats* is the subject.  The question is which of those two words is the real subject.

We aren’t going to be out hanging bats like ornaments from a tree.  If we were, then *hanging* would be the subject and *bats* the object of that *hanging*, and *hanging* therefore a gerund in the old grammar books.  That would make *hanging* the real subject.

But it isn’t.  It’s the bats themselves who are hanging from the ceilings of the  the caves like so many furry stalactites.  They are bats a-hangin’ — they are “bats pendant”, if you would.  Therefore, *hanging* is here acting as an attributive noun modifier, which makes it a participle in the old books.  *Bats* is the real subject.

However, this isn’t an adjective like *interesting* is because it resists intensifiers like *very*. You can’t say *the very interesting bats are *very hanging*. It still retains too much of its verbal nature for that.

So it’s really just an *-ing* word in both cases, and not always of much use to try to figure out which particular flavor we think we’re looking at.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I have no problem with it being the subject of the sentence (that much is obvious), but do have issues with my daughter being taught it's a gerund phrase simply because it IS the subject.  My lit/lang degree screams "NO" but I cannot find adequate documentation in my old grammar texts.

Comment: @user39589 Think of it this way: if you can delete *bats* without substantively changing the meaning of the sentence, then *hanging* is a gerund; otherwise it is a participle.

Comment: I love 'bats pendant' - it has an heraldic ring but, alas, I find only bats volant and bats displayed. A charming alternative term is *rere-mouse*.

Comment: @StoneyB Well, the [ratpenat](http://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratpenat) does figure prominently in the [old heraldry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ratpenat.svg) of the [Crown of Aragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_of_Aragon), but that one is clearly *volant*, not *pendant*.

Comment: @StoneyB Finally found one: http://www.fantasmagoria.eu/kurositsuji-anime-bat-pendant-coat-of-arms :)

Comment: With a spider tergiant to boot!

Comment: In this sentence, _hanging_ is an -ing form used as an adjective, and so a participial adjective. 'Hanging bats' is thus a noun phrase. More tricky to decide is whether the adjective is being used as a **classifier** (_hanging bats_ as opposed to other types) (apparently, Florida yellowtail bats do not hang from ceilings or walls but prefer to hide in cracks and crevices) or a **descriptor** (adding further, nonrestrictive, information).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. *Hanging bats* here obviously means  ‘bats which hang’, since *hanging anything* is not semantically compatible with the verb *populate*.

It is however possible to employ *hanging bats* with *hanging* as a gerund.

1. ***Hanging bats** in the batrack is the batboy's task.* ... Here *hanging* is a gerund and *bats* is its complement.
2. *The great timber baulks over the courtyard, on which condemned criminals were executed, were known as the **hanging bats***. ... Here *hanging* is a gerund employed as an attributive noun, and the construction means  ‘a bat employed in hanging’.

Comment: This reminds me of the difference between *running shoes, running water,* and *running late*.

Comment: @tchrist Yah, *running* would have been a lot easier.

Comment: _Hanging bats_ sounds like a spooky set of printer's ornaments.